# dynamics crm 365 online quickform not rendering

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have a form which has a tab and in this tab is a quickview form. On the quickview form, I have a subgrid and a text field.

The tab has a default state of 'collapsed'. When I open the form, only the text field is displayed. It seems as if the subgrid in no rendering at all.

If I change the tab default state to 'expanded', then when I open the form, the 
subgrid is rendering correctly.

I have tried to refresh the quickform view outlined here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt736908.aspx

But it does not seem to work.

UPDATE:

I have tried the following, but still no success.

FIRST VERSION

```js
// Triggering when the tab is expanded
function onChange(){
  console.log('on change');

   // get quick view form
   var qv = Xrm.Page.ui.quickForms.get("myquickformview");
   qv.refresh();

   // get subgrid
   try {
      qv.getControl(0).refresh();
   }
   catch (e)
   {
       console.log(e);
    }
}
```

SECOND VERSION

```js
function onLoad(){
    console.log('onload');
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_person').addOnChange(refresh);

}

function onChange(){
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_person').fireOnChange();
}

function refresh(){

   console.log('on change');

   // get quick view form
   var qv = Xrm.Page.ui.quickForms.get("myquickformview");
   // get subgrid
   try {
      qv.getControl(0).setVisible(false);
      qv.getControl(0).setVisible(true);
      qv.getControl(0).refresh();
   }
   catch (e)
   {
       console.log(e);
    }

   qv.refresh();

}
```

Any advice appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, Support Ticket is the way to go being online

Answer (score 1):

1.Add `onchange` event handler for the lookup (on which Quick view form is rendered) to have the code to refresh the quick view control.

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lookup_fieldname").addOnChange(function);
```

Keep the below code in function.

```js
var quickViewControl =  Xrm.Page.ui.quickForms.get(“your quick view form name”);
if (quickViewControl != undefined) {
  if (quickViewControl.isLoaded()) {
    quickViewControl.refresh();
  }
}
```

2.Trigger `fireOnChange()` of lookup on tab expanded handler, so that onchange will refresh QVform totally.

```js
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lookup_fieldname").fireOnChange();
```

Got a hint from [this](https://crmprof.wordpress.com/2017/03/16/quick-view-form-and-sub-grid-issue/). I just answered here (in mobile without testing) to unblock you.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but unfortunately it did not work. I debugged the code and no errors are thrown and all controls are found.

Comment: Possible product bug. Another try: put QV inside a section of expanded tab & switch visible (true/false).. Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("TAB").sections.get("SECTION").setVisible(false);